# XML XSLT Display related information in the same group

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML file that I need to transform with XSLT. This is my XML example:

```
<level1>COLORS</level1>
  <level2>COLOR</level2>
  <level3>RED</level3>
<level1>COLORS</level1>
  <level2>COLOR</level2>
  <level3>YELLOW</level3>
<level1>FLAVORS</level1>
  <level2>FLAVOR</level2>
  <level3>SWEET</level3>
<level1>FLAVORS</level1>
  <level2>FLAVOR</level2>
  <level3>SOUR</level3>
```

The requirement is for the output to be:

```
COLORS COLOR RED YELLOW
FLAVORS FLAVOR SWEET SOUR
```

I need to do this in Sharepoint 2007.  I have been researching how to do this with preceding-sibling, following-sibling, for-each-group, etc. but have not been able to work it out either for lack of exposure to these technologies or because Sharepoint won't allow it (SP only knows XSL v.1 and not v.2).
I would appreciate any help that is provided.  Thanks!

Comment: fyi lars is refering to the muenchian grouping method described here! http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Answer (score 2):

**This simple transformation (just one key and just one template)**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:key name="kValues" match="*/*" use="."/>

 <xsl:template match=
  "*/*[generate-id()
      =
      generate-id(key('kValues', .)[1])
      ]">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ' ')"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<t>
    <level1>COLORS</level1>
    <level2>COLOR</level2>
    <level3>RED</level3>
    <level1>COLORS</level1>
    <level2>COLOR</level2>
    <level3>YELLOW</level3>
    <level1>FLAVORS</level1>
    <level2>FLAVOR</level2>
    <level3>SWEET</level3>
    <level1>FLAVORS</level1>
    <level2>FLAVOR</level2>
    <level3>SOUR</level3>
</t>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
COLORS COLOR RED YELLOW FLAVORS FLAVOR SWEET SOUR
```

**Explanation**: Appropriate use of the **[Muenchian grouping method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)**.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:key name="k" match="level1" use="."/>


    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="level1[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('k', .))]"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="level1">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA0;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::level2[1]"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA0;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('k', .)/following-sibling::level3[1]"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="level3">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA0;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input:

```
<root>
    <level1>COLORS</level1>
    <level2>COLOR</level2>
    <level3>RED</level3>
    <level1>COLORS</level1>
    <level2>COLOR</level2>
    <level3>YELLOW</level3>
    <level1>FLAVORS</level1>
    <level2>FLAVOR</level2>
    <level3>SWEET</level3>
    <level1>FLAVORS</level1>
    <level2>FLAVOR</level2>
    <level3>SOUR</level3>
</root>
```

Output:

```
COLORS COLOR RED YELLOW 
FLAVORS FLAVOR SWEET SOUR
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt response.  I will try it!

Answer (score 1):

using your example in the format below

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <root>
    <level1>COLORS</level1>
    <level2>COLOR</level2>
    <level3>RED</level3>
    <level1>COLORS</level1>
    <level2>COLOR</level2>
    <level3>YELLOW</level3>
    <level1>FLAVORS</level1>
    <level2>FLAVOR</level2>
    <level3>SWEET</level3>
    <level1>FLAVORS</level1>
    <level2>FLAVOR</level2>
    <level3>SOUR</level3>
    </root>
```

with this

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
    >
        <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
        <xsl:key name="k1" match="level1" use="."/>
        <xsl:key name="k2" match="level2" use="."/>
        <xsl:key name="k3" match="level3" use="."/>


        <xsl:template match="root">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="level1[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k1', .)[1])]"/>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="level1">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="../level2[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k2', .)[1])][preceding-sibling::level1[1]=current()]"/>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="level2">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="../level3[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k3', .)[1])][preceding-sibling::level2[1]=current()]"/>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="level3">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

the correct results are produced
COLORS COLOR RED YELLOW FLAVORS FLAVOR SWEET SOUR

Comment: I really appreciate the fact that I have received two options in such a short amount of time.  I will try both!  I will use this not only to solve my problem, but also as a learning opportunity.  Thanks again!

Comment: thanks for the comments my solution will work on any ammount of data provided, the other solution will work only if your xml is explicitly as you stated above! ie if under <level3>red</level3> you added <level3>blue</level3> it would not pick it up where as mine would work as wanted!

Comment: Thank you Dimitre.  Even though I don't know these technologies, I agree with the fact that your solution looks much simpler.  I will try it.  I must say though that the other two solutions work perfectly and I'm glad that now I have three different solutions to learn from.  Thanks.

Comment: @user1167307: Did you mean me or Treemonkey? :) Anyway, you are welcome.

Comment: The solution by Dimitre works same way as mine but will save you some keyboard life ;)